# Checking one CheckBox in a ListView checks all of the rest using Flutter

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart, checkbox

I am completly new to Flutter and Stackoverflow. This is my first question to be in fact so please forgive me if I totaly fail at asking this question. I am trying to make a simple Flutter app that provides a ListView of questions and a checkbox beside each. The user can then choose which question they want to answer. My problem is that when the user checks any of the checkboxes then all get checked and vise versa. The questions themselves are retrieved from a backendless database. The code below is what i have so far. I would really appreciate any help anyone can provide me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Questions extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map> questionList;

  Questions(this.questionList);

  @override
  _QuestionsState createState() => _QuestionsState();
}

class _QuestionsState extends State<Questions> {
  bool _questionSelected = true;

  Widget _buildQuestionItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.questionList[index]['question']),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        value: _questionSelected,
        onChanged: (bool val){
          setState(() {
            _questionSelected = val;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemBuilder: _buildQuestionItem,
      itemCount: widget.questionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

Thankful for Mohammed Ashab Uddin suggestions I feel that I am close to getting this thing to work but I am still getting an error

> "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

I think I should have posted the main.dart code where I set the value of the questionList perhaps it is an order of code execution that causes this error so please find my code for main.dart below in hopes it would help in figuring out this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:backendless_sdk/backendless_sdk.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'questions.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'RT Database Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Questions'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  static const String API_HOST = "https://api.backendless.com";
  static const String APP_ID = "<APP_ID>";
  static const String ANDROID_APP_KEY = "<ANDROID_APP_KEY>";
  static const String IOS_APP_KEY = "<IOS_APP_KEY>";

  IDataStore<Map> questionsStore = Backendless.data.of('Questions');
  List<Map> questionsList = [];
  var _questionSelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initBackendless();
    _enableRealTime();
    getQuestions();
  }

  void _initBackendless() {
    Backendless.setUrl(API_HOST);
    Backendless.initApp(APP_ID, ANDROID_APP_KEY, IOS_APP_KEY);
  }

  void _enableRealTime() {
    EventHandler<Map> rtHandlers = questionsStore.rt();

    rtHandlers.addCreateListener((question) {
      setState(() {
        questionsList = List.from(questionsList);
        questionsList.add(question);
      });
    });

    rtHandlers.addUpdateListener((question) {
      setState(() {
        questionsList = List.from(questionsList
            .map((m) => m['objectId'] == question['objectId'] ? question : m));
      });
    });

    rtHandlers.addDeleteListener((question) {
      setState(() {
        questionsList = List.from(questionsList);
        questionsList.removeWhere((m) => m['objectId'] == question['objectId']);
      });
    });
  }

  void _selectQuestion(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _questionSelected = newValue;
    });
  }

  void getQuestions() {
    DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder()
      ..pageSize = 100
      ..sortBy = ['created'];

    questionsStore
        .find(queryBuilder)
        .then((response) => setState(() => questionsList = response));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My Life History"),
      ),
      body: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.5,
        child: Questions(questionsList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `_questionSelected` is a global variable. All the checkbox widgets are using this variable as the value. Therefore, when the variable changes on the `onChanged()` function, all the values are also changed to the value of `_questionSelected`.

In this case, you need to keep track of all the values of the checkbox widget. So, you should use an array rather than a single variable.

What I usually do is, create a new list that will contain only the selected elements.
Remove an element if it is not selected and add an element if it is selected.

```
//generate a list of false values with the length of questionList
List<bool> _questionSelected;

initState(){
   _questionSelected = List<bool>.filled(questionList.length, false, growable: true);
   super.initState();
}

  Widget _buildQuestionItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.questionList[index]['question']),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        value: _questionSelected[index],
        onChanged: (bool val){
          setState(() {
            _questionSelected[index] = val;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: When I edit the code as suggested above I get an error on the length variable of the filled method. It says that Only static members can be accessed in initializers. I tried reading the dart diagnostic message for that error but couldn't understand what it means and how that applies to my code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to initialize the value of _questionSelected at the initState(). I edited my code again.

Comment: I am getting a RangeError and I feel it may be because of perhaps order of code execution. I forgot to include the main.dart code that calls the questions.dart code in my original post. I edited the post to include that code in hopes it may give some indication of the source for the RangeError. I couldn't figure it out myself.

I should add that if I replace the "questionList.length" with the number 3 in the filled method of your code it works. I feel that the questionList is not initialized when questions.dart is called. That is why i also posted the main.dart which calls questions.dart